# How to remove all single slashes from a string while leaving double slashes intact

Tags: java, string, replace

Say you have the following text in a file.:

```
word \  sum \"span class=\\"blahblah\\">java
```

If I were to put the text into a string and use the replace method as follows. :

```
String text = "word \\ sum \\\"span class=\\\\\"blahblah\\\\\">java";
text = text.replace("\\", "");
System.out.println(text);
```

Then String text would be printed as:

```
word   sum "span class="blahblah">java
```

However, I want the double slashes to remain intact. What would I change in order to only remove the single slashes while leaving the double slashes intact?

Desired output:

```
word   sum "span class=\\"blahblah\\">java
```

Comment: By double slashes do you mean slashes in multiples of two i.e. "\\\\" as well as "\\"?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Can there be triple backslashes?

Comment: yes, slashes in multiples of two(i.e. '\\') I want to leave intact. I only want to remove single slashes('\'). The preferred output would be: word   sum "span class=\\"blahblah\\">java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    text = text.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\)", "");
```

Comment: good one, although this doesn't work to remove one slash from triple slashes

Comment: I agree, but there was no requirement about 3+ slashes

Comment: Yup, I just want to point out to the comment by @EJP in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "word \\ sum \\\"span class=\\\\\"blahblah\\\\\">java";
text = text.replace("\\\\", "#$%"); // replace '\\' by something unique
text = text.replace("\\", "");//remove the '\'
text = text.replace("#$%", "\\\\");//get '\\' back
```

Comment: this will not compile: 3rd line is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Look up Regular Expression Lookahead and Lookbehind patterns.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Keep in mind that lookbehind does not work in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove one backslash from any odd length consecutive backslashes:

```
text.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\\\(?!\\\\)","$1")
```

So in the case of

```
text = "word \\ sum \\\"span class=\\\\\"blah\\\\\\\"blah\\\\\">java"
```

or when printed: `word \ sum \"span class=\\"blah\\\"blah\\">java`, the result is:

```
word sum "span class=\\"blah\\"blah\\">java
```